# Internal server error 500(codeigniter, ajax)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I want to check if the user email already exists in the database. For which I have build the following code.

AJAX code:

```
function emailCheck(){
    console.log("hello");
    var email = $("#email").val();;
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>myCon/customerCheck',
        data: {email:email},
        success:function(response){
           $('#test').html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

myCon controller's function:

```
        public function customerCheck(){
            $this->load->model('CustomerModel');
            $res = $this->customerModel->customerMailCheck();
            echo json_encode($res);
        }
```

`customerModel` model's function:

```
        function customerMailCheck(){
            $mail = $this->input->post('email');
            $result = $this->db->get_where('privilege_customer', array('email' => $mail);
            return $result->result();
        }
```

Now whenever I call that function am getting error stating that internal server error 500.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Check your error logs.

Comment: You encode the return data but you don't decode in your JavaScript?

Comment: 500 internal error means in you `controller` file have `system` error  or some other `error'`

Comment: one more replace `data: {email:email},` to `data: {"email":email},`

Comment: @akhilregonda change in config `$config['base_url'] = '';` to `$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].'/project_name/';`

Comment: @VijaySharma I just changed it to $config['base_url'] =  'http://localhost/myCon/'; refreshed my page and called the emailCheck() function, got the same error "POST http://localhost/myCon/myCon/customerCheck 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: Did you changed to your model i aslo post answer for that check that

Comment: Why are you using a url with myCon in it twice twice ?

Comment: It could be that you need a new htaccess. Try some of these https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Comment: Also follow the codeigniter class and filenaming way here only the first letter should be upper case explained here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: @TimBrownlaw first one is folder name and second one is the controller name

Comment: @akhil and you can access that directly? Cant you use http://localhost/myconn/customercheck ? or http://localhost/index.php/myconn/customercheck

Comment: @akhilregonda another good read https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading-a-model

Comment: @TimBrownlaw by using localhost/myCon/myCon/customercheck I can able to access that page directly

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I have added the .htaccess file in which I used the following code:
"<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>"

Comment: ok so your ajax code... how are you loading that?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I have register.php, header.php, footer.php files as views, I have added the ajax code in register.php. onblur of email input field am calling the emailCheck function. whenever the onblur event is called am getting the following error in my console "POST http://localhost/MyCon/MyCon/customerCheck 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution for your problem.

> Please add below code in your header of page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    base_url = '<?=base_url()?>';
</script>
```

> Changes your controller function.

```
public function customerCheck(){
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        $this->load->model('CustomerModel');
        $mail = $this->input->post('email');
        $res = $this->customerModel->customerMailCheck($mail);
        if(!empty($res)) {
            $data['status'] = 'success';
            $data['message'] = 'Email Adress is found';
        } else {
            $data['status'] = 'error';
            $data['message'] = 'Data not found';

        }
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    } else{
        redirect('login/logout');
    }
}
```

> Change Ajax Code

```
function emailCheck(){
    var email = $("#email").val();;
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url  : base_url +'myCon/customerCheck',
        data: {email:email},
        success:function(response){
            if(response.status=="success"){
                 $('#test').html(response.message);
            } else {
                console.log(response.message)
            }
        }
    });
}
```

> CustomerModel model's function:

```
function customerMailCheck($mail){
    $result = $this->db->get_where('privilege_customer', array('email' => $mail));
    return $result->result();
}
```

I hope this will helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the modifications but am still getting the "POST http://[::1]/myCon/myCon/customerCheck 500 (Internal Server Error)" in the console.

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: No change am still getting the error in the console.

Comment: So can you access your page using http://[::1]/myCon/myCon/customerCheck?

Answer (score 0):

One bracket **)** is missing in your model function:

Try this:

```
function customerMailCheck(){
            $mail = $this->input->post('email');
            $result = $this->db->get_where('privilege_customer', array('email' => $mail));
            return $result->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must receive ajax request in controller and pass it to model

myCon controller

```
public function customerCheck(){
        $this->load->model('CustomerModel');    
----->  $mail = $this->input->post('email');       ------v
        $res = $this->customerModel->customerMailCheck($mail);
            echo json_encode($res);
        }
```

Model :

```
function customerMailCheck($mail){

            $result = $this->db->get_where('privilege_customer', array('email' => $mail);
            return $result->result();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

Script : Here you missed Bouble Qutes

```
function emailCheck(){
    console.log("hello");
    var email = $("#email").val();;
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?=site_url()?>myCon/customerCheck',
        data: {"email":email},
        success:function(response){
           $('#test').html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Model : Here you missed `)` in `$result=` line

```
function customerMailCheck() {
    $mail = $this->input->post('email');
    $result = $this->db->get_where('privilege_customer', array('email' => $mail));
    return $result->result();
  }
```

Comment: @akhilregonda change in config `$config['base_url'] = '';` to `$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].'/project_name/';`